# non linear regression scatter plot

Tags: python, matlab, plot, regression, scatter

My data points are:

x =[5.00E-07, 1.40E-06, 4.10E-06, 1.25E-05, 3.70E-05, 1.11E-04, 0.33E-04, 1.00E-03]
y= [494.55, 333.4666667, 333.3333333, 333.1, 303.4966667, 197.7533333, 66.43333333, 67.715]

The x axis on my plot must be exponential!!

I want to make a regression line such as the image added, in an S shape. How do I do this (in matlab or python)?
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62d4g.png)
**UPDATE: I tried:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline     
import numpy as np     

#create data     
x = np.array([5.00E-07, 1.40E-06, 4.10E-06, 1.25E-05, 3.70E-05, 1.11E-04, 3.33E-04, 1.00E-03])     
y= np.array([494.55, 333.4666667, 333.3333333, 333.1, 303.4966667, 197.7533333, 66.43333333, 67.715])     

#define x as 200 equally spaced values between the min and max of original x     
xnew = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)     

#define spline      
spl = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=2)     
y_smooth = spl(xnew)    

#create smooth line chart     
plt.plot(x,y, 'o', xnew, y_smooth)    
plt.xscale("log")    
plt.show()
```

My results are: [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHzoq.png)
How can I make it even smoother? differing the k doesn't make it better.

Comment: what you're doing in your code is interpolation, not regression.

Comment: See my edits. I think the best is to interpolate for log(x) and plot y vs log(x)

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the higher the degree you use for the k argument, the more “wiggly” the curve will be

> Depending on how curved you want the line to be, you can modify the value for k.

try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline
import numpy as np

#create data
x = np.array([5.00E-07, 1.40E-06, 4.10E-06, 1.25E-05, 3.70E-05, 1.11E-04, 3.33E-04, 1.00E-03])
y= np.array([494.55, 333.4666667, 333.3333333, 333.1, 303.4966667, 197.7533333, 66.43333333, 67.715])

#define x as 200 equally spaced values between the min and max of original x 
xnew = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 200) 

#define spline
spl = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=3)
y_smooth = spl(xnew)

#create smooth line chart 
plt.plot(xnew, y_smooth)
plt.show()
```